# ReactDOM error in Vite/React app when adding to Squarespace code block from CDN

Tags: reactjs, vite, react-dom, squarespace

I've built a simple React app using Vite, Typescript, and Tailwind. I can run the app fine locally, but when I am serving it to Sqaurespace via jsdelivr and GitHub, ReactDOM errors out after rendering just part of the app.

This is what is rendered:
[image]

As you can see, the rendering stops after just the first part of the app.

I followed the mapped minified code from the error in squarespace. It *think* it is erroring here at this switch statement:

```js
function unwindInterruptedWork(current, interruptedWork, renderLanes) {
  // Note: This intentionally doesn't check if we're hydrating because comparing
  // to the current tree provider fiber is just as fast and less error-prone.
  // Ideally we would have a special version of the work loop only
  // for hydration.
  popTreeContext(interruptedWork);

  switch (interruptedWork.tag) { // Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tag')
  
  ...
```

Where this function is called there is a null check for `interruptedWork`. However, at the time of the error, it is actually `undefined` rather than `null`. So `unwindInterruptedWork` is called with "undefined" and the error `// Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tag')` happens.

```
function prepareFreshStack(root, lanes) {
  root.finishedWork = null;
  root.finishedLanes = NoLanes;
  var timeoutHandle = root.timeoutHandle;

  if (timeoutHandle !== noTimeout) {
    // The root previous suspended and scheduled a timeout to commit a fallback
    // state. Now that we have additional work, cancel the timeout.
    root.timeoutHandle = noTimeout; // $FlowFixMe Complains noTimeout is not a TimeoutID, despite the check above

    cancelTimeout(timeoutHandle);
  }

  if (workInProgress !== null) {
    var interruptedWork = workInProgress.return;

    while (interruptedWork !== null) { // Here "interruptedWork" is "undefined" instead of "null"
      var current = interruptedWork.alternate;
      unwindInterruptedWork(current, interruptedWork); // called with "undefined"
      interruptedWork = interruptedWork.return;
    }
  }

...
```

I have no idea how to go about debugging from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!